# Python Errno 28 No space left on device

Tags: python, ioerror

I have a simple python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
fo = open("foo.txt", "w")
fo.write( "blah\n");
fo.close() #line 4
```

Running this program produces this:

```
./result.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./result.py", line 4, in <module>
    fo.close()
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

The computer is definitely not out of space.  Another post mentioned checking the inode count, and that is also nowhere near the max.

Comment: This is a Operating System exception. Nothing to do with Python.

Comment: Make sure you are writing where you think you are writing. You could be writing this to a partition that really *is* out of disk space, for example.

Comment: Can you change to the directory in question manually, try to create "foo.txt" in a text editor, and write "blah" to it? You could also do `df -h $(pwd)` from the terminal to see the free space.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Docker?

Docker leaves dangling images around that can take up your space. To clean up after docker, run the following:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -q -f 'status=exited')
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f "dangling=true")
```

This will remove exited and dangling images, which hopefully clears out device space.